# How to get the list of members that reacted to a message in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I just couldn't find a way to do it in discord.py. [Reaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reaction) doesn't include members.

Answer (score 3):

I think I answered in your last post, but to those who did not see it. Here is a snippet from my own bot that implements it. :)

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def test(ctx):

    msg = await client.say('TEST')
    await client.add_reaction(msg, "✅")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    cache_msg = discord.utils.get(client.messages, id = msg.id)
    for reactor in cache_msg.reactions:
        reactors = await client.get_reaction_users(reactor)

        #from here you can do whatever you need with the member objects
        for member in reactors:
            await client.say(member.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a coroutine called [get_reaction_users](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_reaction_users)