# Finding who replied emojies to my message in discord python API

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to get the Discord usernames for a reaction on a message using the Discord.py API.

[image: This is what a reaction is].

Comment: Thanks, I'm new at StackOverflow and my English is bad, so I can't find this documents.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: **discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_reaction_users'**
now I have this problem, which function has a attribute 'get_reaction_users'?
@MrPizzaGuy

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer your question. I don't use Discord.Py. But, like I said, you can check [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: I can't find it on the Docs.

Comment: Did you check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53067638/how-to-get-the-list-of-members-that-reacted-to-a-message-in-discord-py