# Why does reaction list on a message from a bot not show up in the terminal?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm making a bot that would help with emoji suggestions, but I need help with the reaction part, beacuse I cant get the list of reactions on that message. Here's a bit of code:

```
suggestion = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

await suggestion.add_reaction('')
votes = suggestion.reactions
print(votes)
```

So when I run the bot and use the command to run that bit of code, the reaction shows up instantly, but the terminal prints out `[]`, and logically that would mean that votes are none for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

Also, here's the code to run it for yourself:

```
client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='suggestemoji ')

@bot.command()
async def suggest(ctx, name):
    max = 2
    author = ctx.message.author.name
    attachment_url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
    embed = discord.Embed(title="New suggestion!", description=f"User **{author}** suggested an emoji **:{name}:**!", color=0x37ff00)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=attachment_url)
    embed.set_footer(text="Bot made by <cut out for personal reasons>")
    suggestion = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    def check(reaction):
        return str(reaction.emoji) == ''

    await suggestion.add_reaction('')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    cache_msg = discord.utils.get(client.messages, id=suggestion.id)
    #reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
    votes = suggestion.reactions
    print(votes)
```

Comment: maybe you have to sleep to wait for some reaction - like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54661620/1832058

Comment: @furas i tried that, but after 5 seconds it still prints out `[]`

Comment: It is because `suggestion` needs to be populated with the reactions that were added after the variable was stored. You'll have to either fetch the message object once again or use `wait_for('reaction_add')` to capture reacts as they come.

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine I used the second method, but instead nothing was outputted, heres my code: https://pastebin.com/uA5YtjvD

Comment: always put code in question, not on other server - more people will see it. BTW: you have wrong indentations in this code some code is outside function.

Comment: BTW: using Google I found [[rewrite] Adding reactions, but message.reactions is returning "[]" #1686](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1686). It seams you have to get message again to get reactions. It seems code in my previous link also get message again after sleep.

Comment: @furas I saw that github issue too, and also I edited my code a bit, but it outputs an error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'messages'`. Here's the edited code: ```await suggestion.add_reaction('')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    cache_msg = discord.utils.get(client.messages, id=suggestion.id)
    #reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
    votes = suggestion.reactions
    print(votes)```

Comment: by the way I posted that code on pastebin beacuse here it doesn't look that good

Comment: always put code, data, and error message in question, not in comment - and it will look good, and more people will see it. People may not read comment.

Comment: I don't know what `client` is in your code and I can't test it because you didn't create minimal working code which we could test.

Comment: @furas okay, I edited the question, now you can run it with ease, or not, I don't know